# JSON array issue in Spring Boot data JPA

Tags: spring-boot

I have JSON array as follows

```
{
    "enclosedCertifecates": ["Memo", "TC", "Bonafied"]
}
```

I am using MYSQL8 DB for Spring BOOT Datajpa. Below is my ENtity class

```
@Entity
public class Student{
@Id
private int regNo;
private String enclosedCertifecates[];

// setters
// getters

}
```

I am getting error that java.lang.String cannot be casted as java.lang.String. Can Some one please help??

Comment: syntax declaration of array is wrong use this `private String enclosedCertifecates[];`

Comment: Sorry.. I  have typed mistake in the question. It actually private enclosedCertifecates[] . But its not working. same error.

Comment: add the error message with stack trace

Comment: Generally this happens when there is  multiple class loaders. Do you use spring boot devtools can you remove it from your dependencies and try again?

Comment: Yes. I have tried your code. Now Its working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Deadpool, Thanks it worked. I used @Lob . Now I have removed it, and its working fine.